# How to send the "@" symbol with NirCmd sendkeys

Tags: scripting

Using NirCmd sendkeys functions, I am trying to send the @ symbol to firefox to automate logins that contain my email address but can't seem to find the right code for the @ key. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A normal keyboard don't have the `@` key.

Maybe you could try sending `SHIFT` and `2` at the same time.

However, I think AutoHotKey is more suitable for this kind of task.

Comment: That was so obvious and I missed it. Thanks